# Setting paragraph width 2 times the default size

Tags: html, css

```
<p>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="text"/>
</p>
<p> 
  <input type="text"/>
</p>
```

So I have 2 paragraphs ,and I was wondering if it is possible to set the width of the second paragraph 2 times it's normal width in order to be the same size as the one before which has a longer width due to the two input boxes.

Comment: A javascript solution is also  ok?

Comment: I never used javascript I am new to web programming, i was hoping for a css solution.

Comment: Your question does'nt make much sense without your css. p are block elements and will be same width without any CSS.  **your code shows paragraph of same width** what's your question then ? :).  https://jsfiddle.net/yuc95vek/

Comment: Side note: it's not correct to use `<p>` tags in this way. Inputs are not paragraphs of text.

Comment: @RaduSoigan with some CSS added to make sense of the element sizing, this is what your HTML looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/rg8whmcm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `table` tag to put only the two paragraphs. The table cell that has the longest width will adjust all other cell to its width. Since the mentioned that the first paragraph is the longest,see snippet below

Note: paragraph 1 `p1` has a red border with a width of `370px`

```css
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

#p1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 370px;
  border: solid red;
}
#p2{
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id="p1">
        <input type="text" />p1
        <input type="text" />270px
      </p>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id="p2">
        <input type="text"/>p2
      </p>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would not go with using the <p> tag in this table since the input boxed table cell will scale. But since your requirement has to do with <p> this is an approach

Comment: Oh, wow, a table-based design SO answer. For the record, this is a semantically incorrect approach and has been avoided for many years now. There are much better ways to implement this now.

Answer (score 0):

A `<p>` elements default width is 100%, no matter what is in it, except if you either define a width for it or if you make it an `inline` element by applying `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`

It seems you want to stretch the input bos, not the `p` tag? This is done with the `size` attribute in the `input` tag (in the HTML code)

Comment: yes, and I want to define it the width of the first paragraph without guessing it

Comment: they (the  `p` tags`) are both 100% wide - apply a background or a border to them, then you'll see it

Answer (score 0):

Use :nth-child(2) This way you can set all the characteristics for paragraphs and with :nth-child, set the width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  p {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
  p:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```